# Erlang Binary pattern matching unknown quantity

Tags: erlang, binary, design-patterns

Say I have

```
Bin = <<"10=123">>
```

This function

```
binary:split(Bin, <<"10=">>),
```

splits it into

```
[<<"10=">>, <<"123">>]
```

Instead I need it to match the last 3 numbers. 
Even if its 345 or 777.
The one for sure thing is that it will always be 3 numbers.

So it would instead match the entire pattern

Im not too good with binaries but I believe I am looking for something like

```
 binary:split(Bin, <<01,"10=", 3/binary>>),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean but if you only want to match the <<"123">> part then you could simply do:

```
1> <<"10=", Rest/binary>> = <<"10=123">>.
<<"10=123">>
2> Rest.
<<"123">>
```

If you don't want to match at all on the <<"10=">> part just replace it above with "_:3/binary".

If this is what you want then your original way would have worked just as good:

```
1> Bin = <<"10=123">>.
<<"10=123">>
2> [_,Rest] = binary:split(Bin, <<"10=">>).
[<<>>,<<"123">>]
3> Rest.
<<"123">>
```

Comment: I think you are mistaken in what /bitstring means.  It has nothing to do with strings.

Comment: @Peer Of course. You are absolutely right. Removed that part.

Answer (score 4):

binary:part/3 helps?

```
binary:part(Bin, byte_size(Bin), -3).
```

cf: reference doc. http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#part-3